# Running multiple scripts from different languages

Tags: python, script, julia

This is mostly a conceptual question. Is it possible to have two scripts running on a Raspberry Pi, where one is a Julia script, and one is a Python script? In the most general case of this, is there an obvious reason this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that you're not running a weird custom operating system with a minimal kernel, the RPi is running a full fledged version of linux. The applications it comes with are written in C, C++, Java, Perl, Python, and probably others. You'll have to install Julia, but there's no reason the RPi can't handle multiple languages.

Answer (score 11):

You can run any number of scripts with varying programming language. You can think in the direction of using tools like [`Screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) or [`tmux`](https://tmux.github.io/). They basically are used to run scripts in *background or detached mode*. This proves to be quite useful when you have a lot of applications you need to keep track of whilst they are running in the background.

#### Installation on Raspberry Pi

I am a fan of `tmux` over `screen` hence on your Pi you can install `tmux` via the following command line:

```
sudo apt install tmux
```

(`apt-get` install can work too)

#### Working around with `tmux`

Think of a your two scripts running together as a **Session** in `tmux`. Since you have two scripts in mind (**Julia** and **Python**); you should consider running each of the script in it's own **Window**.

Once your `tmux` session starts it will consist of two windows:

1. an empty `bash` shell
2. `myJuliascript`
3. `myPythonScript`

#### Working

if both scripts work well, all you have to do is **attach** to the **Session** and navigate to each **Window** using the `tmux` hot-keys (usually <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>window_Number</kbd>)

### `tmux` Script

Here is a what your `tmux` script would look like (called `sessionScript.sh`):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# 1. Create a detached Session using tmux
/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s MySession

# 2. Use the below line to catch any errors in the scripts
/usr/bin/tmux set-option -t TWIN set-remain-on-exit on

# 3. Create a window for Julia Script
/usr/bin/tmux new-window -d -n 'juliaScript' -t MySession:1 'julia /home/pi/myJuliaScript.jl'

# 4. Create a window for Python Script
/usr/bin/tmux new-window -d -n 'pyScript' -t MySession:1 'python3 /home/pi/myPythonScript.py'

# Safely exit
exit 0
```

### Execution and Handling Session

Once the above mentioned script is written, give executable rights using:

```
 chmod +x sessionScript.sh
```

and execute it using : `./sessionScript.sh`

This will trigger a new `tmux` session called : **MySession** with windows **juliaScript** and **pyScript**

1. In order to **attach** to the script:

   ```
    tmux a
   ```
2. You will be attached to the session and see a blank shell, in order to see how your **Julia** Script is doing use: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
3. For your **python** script use: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
4. If you want to keep the session running and **detach** from the session use: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
5. If you want to kill the complete session: `tmux kill-session`

**Note**:

You can run as many scripts (not infinite though! but a decent number) on the Pi or any Linux machine using `tmux`. Learn it and soon you will love it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is what the OP had in mind, but +1 for good information and in such good detail. I'd give it an extra +1 if I could for using tmux over screen... ;)

Comment: Thought OP's general question could be tackled with a practical workthrough. Plus answer can help for future references on multi-programming applications on Pi.

Answer (score 7):

I second Shan-Desai's suggestion of `tmux`, which is great, but perhaps this is actually overkill for your application. If neither of the scripts is in some way interactive, requires user input etc., you can simply run them in parallel with Bash's `&` operator:

```
$ julia myJuliaScript.jl & python3 myPythonScript.py
```

This will keep the terminal “hanging” while either of the scripts still runs; depending on what you need this for this may not matter. If you want to log out and keep the scripts running, you can use `nohup`, which comes installed by default on most Unixes:

```
$ nohup sh -c 'julia myJuliaScript.jl & python3 myPythonScript.py' &
$ logout
# Scripts keep running
```

This also works with just a single script.

```
$ nohup julia myJuliaScript.jl &
$ logout
```

If the scripts print output to the console, I'd recommend directing it into a file:

```
$ (julia myJuliaScript.jl > jlScript.log) & (python3 myPythonScript.py > pyScript.log)
```

If one of the scripts is really interactive both producing output and requiring input, then `tmux` is indeed probably the best tool.

Answer (score 4):

No, there are no obvious reasons why you wouldn't be able to run two scripts in two languages at the same time. The Pi's just a very wee, relatively low-powered Linux machine and is perfectly capable of doing several things at once.